# Making vue.js component library. Avoid rebuilding it after each edit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, shared-libraries, node-modules

**Intro:** I've generated two projects with vue-cli ~4.2.0:

- `parent-app` - main project
- `dummylib` - library which is imported by `parent-app`. Has a bunch of `.vue` components inside.

Currently, `parent-app` works fine in dev mode with `dummylib` being imported into it. All `dummylib`'s vue-components are rendering ok.

**Problem:** I want to edit `dummylib` and see changes *on the fly*, as it takes place with `parent-app`: without having to rebuild it after each code modification.

**My current library development process**:

1. (`dummylib`): `yalc publish` - assuming it has been built already
2. (`parent-app`): `yalc link dummylib`
3. (`parent-app`): `npm serve` - start local development
4. Editing `dummylib`...
5. (`dummylib`): `npm build` - **!!! Want to avoid this step !!!**
6. (`dummylib`): `yalc publish --push` - After this, I see my edits from (4) being applied...

So are there any options to avoid (5)? I've also thought about monorepo, but decided not to have it currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, got it working by adding:

```
"start": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name dummylib src/main.js --watch --mode development"
```

to `scripts` section in `package.json`